# Changing class style on smaller screen in boostrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am trying sothing with class called .text-center in \boostrap 3?
But i want only on smaller screen to add that to container element.
Tried something like this

col-sm-text-center col-xs-text-center

But does not work ok, is it possible to make it so simple?

Here is the code that is not working

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-text-center col-xs-text-center">
          <h2 class="color-brand">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
          <p class="color-grey">Lorem ispums dolor sit</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work this way. Css prefixes (.col-xs-, .col-sm- etc ) in bootstrap 3 are only for defining what column size will be for different screen sizes while alignment classes are what it is - classes for aligning text within a block.
You could probably use just css3 media queries for that like:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
  .my-fancy-block {
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that, it would be very nice that we can use something i suggested than so little media-querries out of framework